# I'm attempting to connect to MongoDB with a Clojure application, via Docker

Tags: mongodb, docker, clojure, compojure

I have the following docker-compose rules...

```
catalog-service:
    build: ./services/catalog 
    ports: 
        - "2000:3000"
    depends_on:
        - catalog-datastore
    restart: always

catalog-datastore:
    image: mongo:3.0
    command: mongod --smallfiles --quiet --logpath=/dev/null
    ports: 
        - "27017:27017"
```

The following Dockerfile for the clojure app...

```
FROM clojure
COPY . /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
CMD ["lein", "ring", "server"]
```

And the following connection code in my app...

```
(ns catalog.handler
  (:import com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource)
  (:use compojure.core)
  (:use cheshire.core)
  (:use ring.util.response)
  (:require [compojure.handler :as handler]
            [ring.middleware.json :as middleware]
            [clojure.java.jdbc :as sql]
            [compojure.route :as route]
            [somnium.congomongo :as m]))

(def conn
  (m/make-connection "catalog"
                     :host "catalog-datastore"
                     :port 27017))

(defn get-all []
  (m/fetch :catalog))

(defn get-single [id]
  (m/fetch-one
    :catalog
    :where{:_id (Long/parseLong id)}))

(defroutes app-routes
  (context "/catalog" [] (defroutes catalog-routes
                           (GET "/" [] (get-all))
                           (GET "/:id", [id] (get-single)))))

(def app 
  (-> (handler/api app-routes)
      (middleware/wrap-json-body)
      (middleware/wrap-json-response)))
```

When I try to run the app I get the error...

```
java.lang.AssertionError
Assert failed: (connection? conn)
```

Comment: Version of Docker & Compose? Is your mongo container definitely still up? (Run a `docker-compose ps` to check). Also is it completely started in time for the connection attempt? Also btw you don't need to expose the mongo port in the compose file if you don't have any outside (basically non-container) connections to it.

Comment: Does `docker exec -it xxxx_catalog-service_1 ping catalog-datastore` work? Might also be a classical case of the mongo service not being ready yet when your app tries to connect, though considering JVM startup times thats probably not the case. :>

Comment: JHarris - yeah the mongo container was definitely running, I could curl it etc (from the host). I did docker ps as well, it was running. This is in Docker 1.11.1.

Comment: Loads of dependencies get installed when I run docker-compose up, so I don't think it's a race condition between the app and mongo, as the app takes a couple minutes haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://github.com/aboekhoff/congomongo#setup):

```
set the connection globally

(m/set-connection! conn)

or locally

(m/with-mongo conn
  (m/insert! :robots {:name "robby"}))
```

Looks like you missed that bit. :p

Comment: Ahhh! Great spot! Sorry I'm new to Clojure.